# How to disable redis-cli history

Tags: redis

I've searched around the web, but have been unable to find a way to **disable** redis-cli from generating the file *~/.rediscli_history*. My concern is that the file logs AUTH information into the file (more info. here: https://github.com/antirez/redis/pull/2413). Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just set the environment variable REDISCLI_HISTFILE

```
env REDISCLI_HISTFILE=/dev/null redis-cli
```

Comment: Thanks! Interestingly enough, this only shows up in 40 results for Google and most of them are within source code. So it seems like it might not be well known.

Comment: I certainly wasn't aware of it - kudos!

Answer (score 4):

How about some creative soft linking instead?

```
foo@bar:~$ rm .rediscli_history 
foo@bar:~$ ln -s /dev/null .rediscli_history
foo@bar:~$ redis-cli 
127.0.0.1:6379> ping
PONG
127.0.0.1:6379> exit
foo@bar:~$ ls -al .rediscli_history 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 foo foo 9 Sep 30 00:19 .rediscli_history -> /dev/null
```

BTW - the PR you submitted is effective but I'm not sure I like it - perhaps log the AUTH and mask the password?

Comment: That's a pretty clever workaround! I often redirect stdout and stderr there, but never actually link files to it. I'm going to wait a day to see if there's an official way of doing it. If not, I'm fine with marking that as an acceptable solution.

Comment: ps. btw, that was someone else's PR I came across. I agree with your point though.  :)

Comment: I still having that in the output
`127.0.0.1:6379>
127.0.0.1:6379> set a "hello"
HISTORY: /root/.rediscli_history
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> ping
HISTORY: /root/.rediscli_history
PONG
127.0.0.1:6379>`